# Add conditional "allowed_trigger" from Lambda to a Eventbridge Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I am using Eventbridge rules which invokes a lambda function. My goal is to invoke the lambda function only if a variable "enable_eventbridge" is set to true. I am using the lambda module provided by Terraform. I am aware about using dynamic blocks but as per terraform docs, it is not supported in modules

This is the pseudo code:-

```
module "send_email" {
  source       = "terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws"
  create_bus   = false
  create_rules = var.enable_eventbridge
  role_name    = "send_email_sns"
  rules = {
   ........
  }
}
```

Here's my lambda module code:-

```
module "woke" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "~> 5.0"

  allowed_triggers = {
    email_send = var.enable_eventbridge ? {
      principal  = "events.amazonaws.com"
      source_arn = module.send_email.eventbridge_rule_arns["send_email_sns"]
    } : {}
  }
}
```

How do I achieve conditional eventbridge + lambda allowed trigger? The value of enable_eventbridge is set to false. During terraform plan I receive the following output as plan:-

```
principal : ".amazonaws.com"
```

I am aware that `".amazonaws.com"` is an invalid policy. So how do I achieve my goal? Please help.

Comment: Have you actually read the module documentation?

Comment: @MarkoE Do you mean the module documentation for AWS Lambda or Eventbridge? Afaik, it's not possible to add a conditional `allowed_triggers` and keep the other bit as blank i.e. {} Due to that it changes the principal to `".amazonaws.com"` I have fixed it temporarily by using `principal  = "events.amazonaws.com"` instead of an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest#input_allowed_triggers), we can assign empty object `{}` only on the `allowed_triggers` attribute, not on the `allowed_triggers.email_send`. Hence, move the ternary operator to the `allowed_triggers` attribute, and it will resolve the invalid principle `.amazonaws.com` issue.

```
allowed_triggers = var.enable_eventbridge ? {
     email_send =  {
      principal  = "events.amazonaws.com"
      source_arn = module.send_email.eventbridge_rule_arns["send_email_sns"]
    }
  } : {}
```

Comment: Well, if there's a scenario where there are more than one `allowed_triggers`, I reckon this might fail to work .

Comment: As per the current version, you can apply control only on allowed_triggers level, not at their children level. And, it applicable to event bridge rules as well.

Comment: I achieved this by creating an if condition kinda scenario. For example:- if enable_eventbridge is true then create 2 allowed triggers, if not then create only 1. It makes the code redundant but didn't find any other workarounds. Also, I had to use `create_targets = var.enable_eventbridge` in the `module "send_email" {...}` part.